# Admob issue with rewarded video android studio

Tags: android, admob, adcolony, rewardedvideoad

I was trying to integrate adMob rewarded video using Adcolony Network as third part. I did all the stuff such as integrating the sdk etc... It doesn't work with my Unit ID but with another one it works. I don't think it's a code issue, this is the Log:

`E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AdColony: AdColony methods used before initialization, Activity reference is null. Disabling AdColony until next launch.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1442
                  Process: com.example.utente.guessimageferes, PID: 868
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
                      at com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter.a(SourceFile:474)
                      at com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter$9.run(SourceFile:514)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@c50de45 time:2838444
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 868 SIG: 9
Application terminated.`

Than the app crash. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you mean you’re trying to use several SDKs separately (like via GP staged roll out) or at the same time (mediation) ?
I suppose you want to use Adcolony mediation, and I saw AdMob among their mediation partners http://support.adcolony.com/customer/en/portal/articles/678369-mediators-network-aggregators-f-a-q . Most likely there’s a conflict between SDKs in your case, if you’re implementing them out of AdColony mediation network. I’d suggest to contact their support and would ask them to check my APK. Or you can try implement Adcolony SDK via AdMob mediation.
Anyway, there are more cool solutions among mediators (I’d say that AdColony list of mediating partners is not that big) that support AdMob and other networks, pretty sure you’ll find something suitable.